# image set has an unassigned child

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on an app in Xcode for a few months now. I came back to work on it after not having looked at it for a while and suddenly, I had 174 issues.

All of my images on the storyboard were replaced with question marks, with the error:

> The image set __ has unassigned children

In `Assets.xcassets` all of the images are labelled as unassigned:

[image: An example]

I don't know what to make of this, as it was all working fine a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the asset catalog's Attributes inspector, check some checkboxes, like Universal or iPhone and iPad. Now you will see slots for the resolutions such as "1x", "2x", and "3x". Those slots are where your images need to go.

Comment: This happened to me recently, and all resolutions were filled but removing and re-adding the image set fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old one, but recently I got this problem after I merged 2 branches and encountered conflicts. 2 problems :

1. I got this warning and could not see anything in the attributes inspector.
2. However I resolved the conflicts it just doesn't seem to work.

All you have to do is Clean build your Xcode. Navigate away from .xcassets. Come back to .xcassets, you should be seeing the attributes inspector now.

Check the scales option. I previously had it to single scale but now it was changed to individual scales. On changing it back I got another row in the image set stating Unassigned. I just dragged this to the single scale row. And woila !

Answer (score 5):

It is likely that your Image Sets are missing or have corrupt `Contents.json` files.

Each Image Set contains a `Contents.json` file. To see if your Image Sets have one, right click on an Image Set and click "Show in Finder". You should see your images and a `Contents.json` file.

This issue with your `Contents.json` file may have occurred by modifying, moving, or adding images outside of Xcode (e.g. through the Finder).

You can recreate the `Contents.json` file by re-adding your assets in Xcode or manually creating the file. It should look something like:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "image.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "image@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "filename" : "image@3x.png",
      "scale" : "3x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An umlaut in the file name also gives this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the lazy solution if you don't have time fixing Content.json file.

1.In the same Assets.xcassets folder where the images live Make a new folder say 'AutoFixedImages'.

2. Select all images which have the yellow ⚠️ complaining about having unassigned child
3. Drag them to the new folder
4. Command + S to save.
5. That's it!

Disclaimer: This hack way worked on my machine so it's not guaranteed to work on every other machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when select

```
Scales: Individual and Single Scales
```

As a variant you can just reimport it

Answer (score 0):

You can set its scale to single scale and then move the image to "All".
This did it for me.

Comment: It already answered above, post your answer only if you have additional info about it